# Store only date without time in a database

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

How can I send **the date only** from Java into a MySQL table that has a column of the `DATE` data type? I can achieve that by saving string into the database, but is there a better way?

I am working on attendance of employees without time in and time out. So I only need to store the date.

Comment: @nhgrif: Yes, you are right. Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For storing **only the date**, you need the `DATE` data type.

---

MySQL has three data types for storing date and time values:

> - `DATE`  is used for values with a *date* part but **no *time*** part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in '`YYYY-MM-DD`'
>   format.
> - `DATETIME` type is used for values that contain **both** *date* and *time* parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in '`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`' format.
> - `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain **both** *date* and *time* parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '`1970-01-01 00:00:01`' UTC to '`2038-01-19 03:14:07`' UTC.

More details can be found in the official MySQL Reference Manual
[The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), where the above quote is from.

Comment: I know about Data datatype in MySQL but how can I send value from Java, Sorry If I was not clear enough but I want to know how can I get current Date from Java to store in (Date)MySQL

Comment: Why don't you use the server's date: `CURRENT_DATE()`?

Comment: That helped, *THANKS* I was struggling to find java datatype for past 2 hours.
I used CURRENT_DATE() to store and to retrieve I used 
WHERE DATE(date) = CURRENT_DATE() [found from another post]

Answer (score 3):

```
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
  String input = "2014-01-19";  // capture the value you pass from attendance application
  Date t; 
  try { 
      t = ft.parse(input); 
      System.out.println(t); 
  } catch (ParseException e) { 
      System.out.println("Unparseable using " + ft); 
  }
```

Comment: You could provide a basic explaination next time so newbies can know what's actually your solution about